# How to get the temporary credentials for aws using identity token?

Tags: amazon-cognito

Usecase : I want to limit access to my API gateway paths using federated identites.

For that i need to get AWS temporary credentials by using my ID token. I got my Id token but i donot know how to get  temporary credentials using Id token.

Here is am passing ID token to cognito credentials map

```
  var data = {
      UserPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
      ClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(data);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if (cognitoUser != null) {
      cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, result) {
          if (result) {
              console.log('You are now logged in.');

              // Add the User's Id Token to the Cognito credentials login map.
              AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                  IdentityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
                  Logins: {
                    'cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ap-south-1_G7YbVxxxx': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                  }
              });
          }
      });
  }
```

How to get temporary credentials ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got temporary credentials using below snippet

```
 AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err,data) {
      if (!err) {
        var id = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
        var key = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
        var secretkey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
        var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
        console.log('Cognito Identity ID '+ id);
        console.log('Cognito Key '+ key);
        console.log('Cognito Secret Key '+ secretkey);
        console.log('Cognito SessionToken '+ sessionToken);
      }
    });
```

Comment: How can we use this temp credentials for access to aws services? can you mention the name of function or method used for that? Am bit stuck now.

Comment: Check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#using-temp-creds-sdk